# ActionScript 3 - Can you manipulate a 3d object using AS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, 3d

I have seen tutorials on creating a 3d character in flash. Is there a way to manipulate (animate and move) this 3d character with actionscript 3? If so, could you guide me with some links?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do a bit of reading up on a 3rd party library to help you to achieve this. One such library is [Away 3D](http://away3d.com/) which can be used to manipulate 3d characters in Flash.

The process goes like:

- Build a model in a 3D package
- Load it in to away3d

I am not certain but I think animations are supported in a Collada file but its moving so fast that maybe other formats are supported. I know they were working on their own format.

Anyway if you head over there and maybe post on their forums or look at some of the examples, you should get the idea.